# Python3 & Tkinter, list.sort list of objects made of StringVar

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, tkinter

I have an Python3 app that uses a tkinter interface to collect & edit info stored in a MySQL database. The data consist of several tables, and each table row is represented by a Class (called 'Action' here) made of several StringVar(), which are sometimes displayed with buttons to remove or insert new rows. Class members are stored in the class variable '_registry' for various manipulations.

After creating a new row (in the app, not the db), the user can enter data that's out of the natural sequence, so I'd like to sort the list based on one of the StringVar ('date') before displaying it again. Although the database can handle this trivially, and there are very likely other simple ways to get this done, it seems like list.sort should be able to do it, but I can't figure out how to get the key to work.

Here's the **init** of the class without other functions:

```
class Action: 
    _registry=[]
    def __init__(self, date, quantity, temp, pressure, notes):
        self.date=StringVar()
        self.quantity=StringVar()
        self.temp=StringVar()
        self.pressure=StringVar()
        self.notes=StringVar()
        self.date.set(date)
        self.quantity.set(quantity)
        self.temp.set(temp)
        self.pressure.set(pressure)
        self.notes.set(notes)
        Action._registry.append(self)
```

Here's a not too difficult way to reach the data I'm trying to sort on:

```
>>> Action._registry[1].__dict__['date'].get()
'2015-08-25'
```

And here are some of my failed attempts to get list.sort to use the contents of the 'date' StringVar.

```
>>> list.sort(Action._registry, key=lambda __dict__['date'].get())
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    list.sort(Action._registry, key=lambda __dict__['date'].get())
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> list.sort(Action._registry, key=attrgetter('date'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: StringVar() < StringVar()

>>> list.sort(Action._registry, key=itemgetter('date'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'Action' object is not subscriptable

>>> list.sort(Action._registry, key=attrgetter(Action._registry.__dict__['date'].get()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

It seems like list.sort would implicitly apply the key function to _registry, but I can't find a syntax that works with the required '.get()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't quite get the syntax right for the lambda. You need an argument and a colon. Try:

```
list.sort(Action._registry, key=lambda item: item.__dict__['date'].get())
```

---

Additional style tip: it is idiomatic to call `sort` as a method of the object you're sorting, rather than literally doing `list.sort`.

```
Action._registry.sort(key=lambda item: item.__dict__['date'].get())
```